# How do I create and array of 10 numbers in PL/SQL and sort it in ascending order

Tags: arrays, plsql

I am trying to combine two arrays, so the values are corelated. I think I've got the code for that part below - but it doesn't work. After this, I want to have them ordered in ascending order too. I'm new to PL/SQL, so any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

```
CREATE
type sarray is varray(10) of varchar2(10);
type sno is varray(10) of char(2);

names sarray;
serialno sno;
newtable sarray;

BEGIN

 names:= sarray            (Smith','Diaz', 'Manny', 'Ike','Cruise','Roberts','Fuller','Calabrese' ,'Sharp     e','Khanna');
serialno:= sno('2','4','5','6','9','1','3','7','8', '10');

newtable:= serialno MULTISET UNION names;

FOR i in serialno.first..serialno.last

LOOP
DBMS_output.put_line (i || '. ' || serialno(i));
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: If you're having a problem with some code, paste it into your question so we can help!

Comment: replace the assignment of `names` above with `names:= sarray            ('Smith','Diaz', 'Manny', 'Ike','Cruise','Roberts','Fuller','Calabrese' ,'Sharp   e','Khanna');` i.e. `Smith'` needs a quote before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. What do you mean by "combining" them? Correlated? How? You should provide INPUT as well as desired OUTPUT.

In the meantime, have a look at this code. It uses predefined collections (owned by `SYS`, one for strings - `ODCIVarchar2List`, another for numbers, `ODCINumberList`). I put some values in there and displayed them as they are (no sorting), and sorted by using the `TABLE` function.

```
SQL> declare
  2    names    sys.odcivarchar2list;
  3    serialno sys.odcinumberlist;
  4  begin
  5    names    := sys.odcivarchar2list('Smith', 'Diaz', 'Manny');
  6    serialno := sys.odcinumberlist(3, 1, 2);
  7
  8    dbms_output.put_line('--> display SERIALNO/NAMES "as is"');
  9    for i in serialno.first..serialno.last loop
 10      dbms_output.put_line(i ||'. '|| serialno(i) ||', '|| names(i));
 11    end loop;
 12
 13    dbms_output.put_line('--> display NAMES alphabetically');
 14    for cur_r in (select column_value from table(names) order by column_value)
 15    loop
 16      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.column_value);
 17    end loop;
 18  end;
 19  /
--> display SERIALNO/NAMES "as is"
1. 3, Smith
2. 1, Diaz
3. 2, Manny
--> display NAMES alphabetically
Diaz
Manny
Smith

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you! I wanted this result, but in order of serial number like 1. Diaz 2.Manny 3. Smith etc. I now know how to do this from your code by selecting the serial number column and ordering it. Can I do the reverse too for descending order? So that the display is 3.Smith, 2.Manny 1.Diaz etc?

Comment: So, what should be desired output?

Comment: Desired output would be --> Serial number is ascending order 1.Diaz 2.Manny 3.Smith and ----> Serial number in descending order 3.Smith 2.Manny 1.Diaz .

Comment: That's what the output shows (in ascending order), doesn't it? Below the "--> display NAMES alphabetically" comment. put `order by column_value desc` if you want descending order.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!